# Adding Swift ViewController to an old project. Storyboard problems

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Working in Xcode 6.x with a project created with Xcode 5.0 is a nightmare. 
I need to add a new controller to this project and I need to create it in Swift. 
I create the new View Controller and I add it to the project. When I move to the storyboard I can't assign the just created class to a viewController. I've already tried to press "Enter" on the module textfield and so on... but nothing happens it just can't recognize the new new class.

If I try to assign the Class to a controller even if the storyboard "autocomplete" doesn't recognize the class, when I launch the project I get this error:

```
Unknown class MyViewController in Interface Builder file
```

The code of the controller is just:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Any hints? I can't publish my application since I'm stuck on this problem by 2 weeks... it's absurd.

Comment: Is your XCode 5 project written in Objective C ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you import your Swift Class for Objective-C?

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Importing Swift into Objective-C

Comment: Where I'm supposed to import the Swift Class? it's only used via Storyboard.